# 404 error and Uncaught Promise in react-redux app

Tags: promise, react-redux, http-post, http-status-code-404

I am getting a warning message in my react-redux app I'm building upon entering my Settings area that "the value for prop textarea shouldn't be null." Then upon saving new settings, regardless of what section.. ie- if I change my username or bio or both, I get

```
POST https://conduit.productionready.io/api/user 404 (Not Found)
```

as well as another error that reads

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'errors' of null
```

...I was getting this error before and it was due to my not using the back tick character instead of normal single quotes for string interpolation when providing the API URL. I remember changing my normal quotes to the back tick (button right above tab) and fixed that routing problem. I'm guessing the problem lies within my routing setup but I'm not sure... My repo link is below. Notice if you decide to clone, that you can sign up a new user but you can't edit your info entered in the settings section.  Thanks! [REPO LINK](https://github.com/rockomatthews/react-projects/tree/thursday)

Answer (score 0):

the error was due to me getting salty and inputting a quick password when signing up a user instead of using a normal one that filled requirements of a password. The only problem is my errors for password requirements aren't being displayed.